# Change counter value to string

Tags: python, python-3.x

This project is due in an hour and I have tried every method i know but i just can't get this one part to work. Really need help. I want to change the counter values one the results have been added up so instead of printing the total of each counter, i want to print a string

```
# Compare countA to distance:
def raceAlgorithm(jack, slow, thunder) :
    # Race start point
    countA = 0

    # Length of the race
    distance = 20

    # message afer race is done
    msg = '\nRace Finished\nGetting results.'

    while countA != distance :
        dice = randint( 1, 6 )
        sleep( 1 )
        countA += 1

        if dice <= 2 :
            jack += 1
            # print(a)
        elif dice <= 4 :
            slow += 1
            # print(b)
        else :
            thunder += 1
            # print(c)
        if jack + slow + thunder == distance :
            print( msg )
            Position.append(jack)
            Position.append( slow )
            Position.append( thunder )
            Position.sort( reverse=True )

            # the horses totals
            print( *Position, sep='\n' )

            if Position[0] == jack:
                print( '\nThe winner is: ' + a )
            elif Position[0] == slow :
                print( '\nThe winner is: ' + b )
            elif Position[0] == thunder :
                print( '\nThe winner is: ' + c )
            else :
                print( )
```

Example if jack gets 10 and slow gets 5, instead of print 10 and 5 i want the result to be the name of a horse. The problem is since the result for each horse is random each time, i can't change the specific interger. I need to instead change the it before it gets added to the list. So if jack gets to its prints jack on this list in the position it comes.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Position` list to a list that contains both names and values, then you can sort by the values and print both.

```
from operator import itemgetter

Position = [('jack', jack), ('slow', slow), ('thunder', thunder)]
Position.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(*Position)
print('\nThe winner is:', Position[0][0])
```

Comment: I meant the print(*Position) list. The one there works.

Comment: It would be better if you used a list of tuples or dictionaries, then you could put the horse names and scores together.

Comment: Believe me i know this can be done much better but unfortuantely our lecturer doesnt go into to much complicated stuff so we are left trying to do most of this ourselves. Im pretty much a novice hence why im here.

Comment: how would i go about implemeting the value of the counters. I cant append anymore

Comment: You are a legend

Comment: You don't need to append, you just create the list the way I showed.

Comment: can you help with one more thing.

Comment: if Position.index(jack) == mySelection.index(jack):
ValueError: 22 is not in list

Comment: Is that using my change with putting tuples in the `Position` list? It should then be `Position.index(('jack', jack))`

Comment: ill edit and show you the whole code it will make more sense.

Comment: You should put your code in the question, not edit my answer.

Comment: Don't replace your original code, add it at the end.

Comment: sorry im still new to this site.

Comment: this has the whole thing. works up to the point when its checking if your horse is in first position. i also posted the traceback error